# Telerik's RadListView is not drawing items after updating datasource

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I'm using the **[RadListView](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/listview-overview.html)** control from **[Telerik UI for WindowsForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)**.

What I'm doing step by step is this:

1. Set a DataSource to the control.
2. Manually scroll the vertical scrollbar to down
3. After a timer ticks, the datasource is renewd at runtime.

At this point, after scrolled and the datasource has changed, the scrollbar remains in the same position (as I expected), but the listview does not properly update the layout, any item is drawn in the control.

The only way I found to solve this issue is manually scrolling to up (only to up).

I tried to use the `EnsureItemVisible`, `PerformLayout`, `Invalidate` and the `ScrollTo` methods, I also toggled the state of the `Visible` property, but anything fixed the layout issue.

How I can fix it?.

Comment: what is the DataSource - what type of object?  Most controls wont "see" changes to a simple `List(of T)` or to the items in it.

Comment: @Plutonix it is an IEnumerable of a custom type that just exposes some string properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView did not get updated because your data source does not support notifications. In order to get this going, your data source should implement IBIndingList and your objects should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. For example, instead of IEnumerable, you can use BindingList. An example of this is available in [this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-reflecting-custom-object-changes-in-rgv.html) - even though the article uses RadGridView, on the data source side, the approach is the same.

Then you could have look at the [DataBinding article](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/listview-databinding.html) for RadListView itself.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to call Application.DoEvents()?

Comment: This is not an answer and it is not good advice.  See: [Is DoEvents evil](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/)

Comment: @Plutonix: I just tried to help... I had some issues with telerik components sometime ago and Application.DoEvents() did worked for me....